# TypeError: 'FormData' object is not iterable

Tags: python, asynchronous, io, discord.py, typeerror

```
url = f"https://chat.miscguild.xyz/render.png?m=custom&d={dailygexp}&t=1"

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                image_data = BytesIO(await resp.read())
                await session.close()

        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(image_data, 'dailylb.jpg'))
```

When I run this, it keeps giving the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "/home/container/libs/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/cogs/hypixel.py", line 1339, in dailylb
    await ctx.send(file=discord.File(image_data, 'dailylb.jpg'))
  File "/home/container/libs/discord_components/dpy_overrides.py", line 371, in send_override
    return await send(channel, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/container/libs/discord_components/dpy_overrides.py", line 306, in send
    data = await state.http.send_files(
  File "/home/container/libs/discord/http.py", line 187, in request
    for params in form:
TypeError: 'FormData' object is not iterable
```

I didn't get this error before I updated all my modules to the latest version. Revering back to the old version could probably fix I but I don't get the point of doing that.

Comment: The error is in `for params in form:`. `form` does not support `for x in form`. try to get the data another way

Comment: What do you suggest I do?

Comment: try to get the data another way. i can't make a more precise statement because 1) i am not familiar with the discor.py api and 2) don't know the context of the code that is causing the error. On a side node i suggest learning how to read error messages.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have an error and I have no idea how to rectify it.